# Append incremental number to multiple uploaded images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Append incremented number to multiple uploaded images using JavaScript

I'm trying to upload multiple images to our HP Records Manager Database using the ServiceAPI .NET SDK. Written in ASP.NET MVC.

The images upload successfully but they all have the same Title as it uses the same input field.

I want to be able to create a loop that will append an incremented number to the end each Record Title. (e.g Upload_1, Upload_2, Upload_3....and so on)

```
<form action="Record" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="gpsearchtitle" type="text" name="RecordTypedTitle" value="" required="True"/>
<input id="choose" type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="appendNo()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way of appending a incremented number using JavaScript?

I have tried doing this:

```
<script>
    function appendNo(){
        var inp = document.getElementById('choose');
        var txt = document.getElementById('gpsearchtitle')
        for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length;) {
            var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
            txt.value = txt.value + "_" + i;
            i++;
        }}
</script>
```

However, this adds the incremental count to all image Titles. For example if i upload 4 images the Titles show up as, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3

Comment: If you're uploading multiple files using one `input[type=file]` element you would need to do that on the server. The fact is that you have one `#gpsearchtitle` element which you're changing as many times as the number of files you are uploading.

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable 'name' inside the for loop?

Answer (score -1):

try changing one line

```
txt.value = txt.value + "_" + i;
```

should be

```
txt[i].value = txt[i].value + "_" + i;
```

Comment: Thanks @oMikeY, but updating that line did not make a difference. Infact, the Title didn't get anything appended to it.

Comment: No wonder. Since txt is obtained by getElementById, it is not an array. So txt[i] is undefined.

Comment: Add to your example the current HTML output you got for your original setup and I'll get that fixed.

Comment: Thanks @oMikeY. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for. Please elaborate.